# Is there a word that means "trans-compilation result"?

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction

A compiler takes source code and produces "binary" code.

A trans-compiler (or "transpiler") takes source code and produces `???` code?

I wouldn't like using the word `source` again because that is what humans write, and something isn't source if it is automatically produced by something from something else.

Is there an accepted term to mean trans-compilation output?

Comment: I notice a downvote.  Which stack exchange site do I post this question on?

Comment: Hi Ira, looking at Wikipedia, those terms are best.  Can you delete your comment and add an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase I think you should use is one of two:

- translated code
- generated code